# Change event.target.value type on Select

Tags: javascript, clone

I would like change Select value type on `onChange` event.

I've try to clone my object :

```
const test = {
  ...event
}
```

But no result.

Is it possible to clone event.target with new value ?

Comment: whats that code? can you post enough code for us to look and solve?

Comment: What do you mean by _clone event.target with new value_?